# What best way to pass @PathVariable to my all JSP pages without add it to ModelAndView?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I change my path from:

/user/home
/user/history
...

to

/{orgId}/home
/{orgId}/history
...

So for all /{orgId}/* pages I need **orgId** on my JSP page to construct right links. How to do it without to get @PathVariable in each method and pass it to ModelAndView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ControllerAdvice and ModelAttribute

```
@ControllerAdvice
class Advice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("orgId", "value1");

    }
}
```

As of Spring 4, @ControllerAdvice can be customized through annotations(), basePackageClasses(), basePackages() methods to select a subset of controllers.